# Анимация editview

Tags: android, kotlin

Как я могу сделать editview так, чтобы он работал как в калькуляторе от гугл, например? То есть, текст вводился не с клавиатуры, и вообще клавиатура не должна работать, при этом текст можно было бы скопировать, вставить. А также, если кто знает, я бы хотел знать как сделать анимацию уменьшения и увеличения размера текста, важно что есть уменьшается не бесконечно, а по итогу достижения минимального размера, текст вводился бы как обычно

Comment: Можно немного уточнить вопрос, пожалуйста?

Comment: @Анастасия, добавил изменения, надеюсь не слишком запутано стало

Comment: есть такой класс KeyboardView, с помощью которого вы можете создать любой вид кнопок ввода, сохранив курсор и все другие возможности клавиатуры

Answer (score 0):

По первой части вопроса: чтобы текст в edit Text вводился не с клавиатуры. Как вариант, использовать Buttons и парочку атрибутов самого EditText. Для примера три кнопки и одно поле ввода.

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/editText"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:inputType="none" //Тип вводимых данных - none
           android:textIsSelectable="true" // Оставляем возможность копировать текст
           android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_below="@id/editText"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:weightSum="3">
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn1"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:text="1"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="50dp"/>
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn2"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:text="2"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="50dp"/>
       <Button
           android:id="@+id/btn3"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:text="3"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="50dp"/>
       </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        
        EditText editText;
        Button btn1, btn2, btn3;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
            btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
            btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    
            View.OnClickListener btnClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (v.getId()){
                        case R.id.btn1:
                            editText.setText(editText.getText().append("1")); 
                 //Обрабатываем нажатие каждой кнопки, раз не пользуемся клавиатурой
                            break;
                        case R.id.btn2:
                            editText.setText(editText.getText().append("2"));
                            break;
                        case R.id.btn3:
                            editText.setText(editText.getText().append("3"));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            };
    
            btn1.setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
            btn3.setOnClickListener(btnClicked);
        }
    }
```

Насчет уменьшения текста - это уже другой вопрос, но мне кажется можно думать в сторону того, чтобы отслеживать количество символов, и когда это значение больше определенного, уменьшать, например, шрифт.

Надеюсь, этот ответ будет вам полезен.

Comment: По поводу кнопок, да, но мне нужно чтобы при этом был виден курсор, и можно было копировать и вставлять текст. А по поводу уменьшения, да так можно, но мне бы хотелось чтобы это происходило с плавной анимацией, как её описать не знаю, поэтому и сказал как в калькуляторе от гугл

Comment: Ясно, значит, не совсем правильно вас поняла